# Extract values from column to use in calculated measure formula

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have TABLE A

In that table I have a measure with values like so:

```
Targets|
--------
   4   |
   5   |
   6   |
```

In the same table I have a calculated column (summed totals) like so:

```
Totals |
--------
  10   |
  11   |
  12   |
```

Because this is a direct query data source, query editor is disabled and manipulation must be done through DAX formulas.

I would like to do a simple operation of Targets-Totals

Code I've tried for a **calculated column**:

```
test = TableA[targets] - TableA[totals]
```

However this results in an error:

```
The column TableA[test] cannot be pushed to the remote data source and cannot be used in this scenario.
```

How can I create a new column with the above operation considering the fact that one column is a 'measure ' and the other a 'calculated column'

Comment: Can you update your question, How can you have a measure in a column, and how can you have a calculated column on a DQ table, I think you are mixing up the terminology for what each are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you will need a measure that does a row by row calculation, but not as a calculated column. For this you will need [SUMX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax) which will do a iteration.

Your measure should be:

```
New Measure = SUMX(TableA, [targets] - [totals])
```